# jquery Accordion open and close

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a FAQ-site I user this little snippet for opening the questions

```
var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
   allPanels.slideUp();
   $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
   return false;
});
```

This works fine and if I click on the second question the first answer will be hidden.

How does it work so I can click on the first question and another click on the first question would hide the first answer.

Comment: A jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible This accordion will close when clicked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) to toggle the state based on the current state of the element.

```
$(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
```

You can do:

```
var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
   allPanels.not($(this).parent().next().slideToggle()).slideUp();
   return false;
});
```